# How to implement jQuery's .not()?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I have code like:

```
document.onmousedown = function(){
    alert('test');
}
```

Now, except the element with ID "box", clicking should call this function, i.e. the equivalent of jQuery's `.not()` selector.

The jQuery code would be:

```
$(document).not('#box').mousedown(function(){
     alert('test');
});
```

How can I achieve the same thing without using jQuery?

*Edit:* I don't want jQuery code, but i want an action similar to the `.not()` selector of jQuery in Javascript.

*Edit:* I am making an addthis-like widget.  It is a 10kb file which will show a popup when a text is selected.  It will not use jQuery.

In my case, when a text is selected, a popup is shown. When the document is clicked somewhere other than the widget, the widget should disappear.

Comment: jQuery is Javascript.  Also, that jQuery code won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this properly, you need to check whether `e.target || e.srcElement` or any of its parents has `id === 'box'`.

For example: (with jQuery)

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('#box').length)
        return;

    //Do things
});
```

Without jQuery:

```
function isBox(elem) {
    return elem != null && (elem.id === 'box' || isBox(elem.parentNode));
}
document.onmousedown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (isBox(e.target || e.srcElement))
        return;
    //Do things
};
```

Alternatively, you could handle the `mousedown` event for the `box` element and cancel bubbling.

Comment: +1 and accepted your ans thanks very much Slaks, u r really great !

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way that should work:

```
document.onmousedown = function(e){
   var event = e || window.event;
   var element = event.target || event.srcElement;
   if (target.id !== "box") { alert("hi"); } 
}
```

or if you would like it to be reusable with different ids:

```
function myNot(id, callback) {
    return function (e) {
       var event = e || window.event;
       var element = event.target || event.srcElement;
       if (target.id !== id) { callback(); } 
    }
}
```

and to use it:

```
document.onmousedown = myNot("box", function () {
    alert("hi");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way I can come up with for what you're trying to do is to set a `document.onmousedown` event and then halt event propagation on the `box.onmousedown` event. This avoids creating a large number of `onmousedown` events all over the document, and avoids having to recurse through the entire parent hierarchy of a node every time an event is triggered.

```
document.onmousedown = function() {
    alert("Foo!");
};
document.getElementById("box").onmousedown = function(e) {
    alert("Bar!");
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        e.cancelBubble = true;          
    }
};
```